Why haven't AI composite images been distributed in the UnitedHealthcare CEO murder investigation?
I think everyone who has read the news in the past few days has seen coverage of the UnitedHealthcare CEO shooting.  The suspect was subjected to videotaping at least 13 times that day, with multiple images from each contact.  I was assuming that by now these would have been collated into a cinema-quality AI composite image (or even video) by authorities, and that internet commentators would be casting him in a large number of less dignified roles.  But I don't see any sign of either in a web search.  Question:  what is the major practical difficulty that has prevented AI from generating likely images of his uncovered face and body?

For use in law enforcement/court proceedings, it is important to have unadulterated footage. If AI adds details that weren't there, it would be unsuitable as evidence.

@OliverMason - in this case, there was abundant evidence, and all they needed was to get hold of the suspect somehow.  The original recordings could still be used for trial.

Because people with common facial features are not more likely to be guilty than others, and that's what it would produce.
